# how to list dynamically radiobuttons contained in listTiles in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i would like to show a list of radiobuttons? this radiobuttons are contained in ListTile widget, i tried some code but nothing appears : 
when i put a single radiobutton , this appears but when i put a listview nothing appears on the page including others widgets

```
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {


          return StoreConnector<MMpataState, MMpataViewModel>(
       converter: MMpataViewModel.convertStateToViewModel,
       builder: (BuildContext context, MMpataViewModel vm) {
      // print(vm.state.subscriptions2);
        if (vm.state.isSubscriptions2loaded &&
         vm.state.subscriptions2.length < 1) {
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Aucune donnée"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "Nous n'avons trouvé aucune souscription pour le produit 
     sélectionné.",

            ),
          ),
        ),
        );
        }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(!vm.state.isSubscriptions2loaded ? "Chargement ... " : 
     vm.state.subscriptions2[0].product.libelle),
        ),
        body: MMpataLoader(
          inAsyncCall: _isLoading || !vm.state.isSubscriptions2loaded,

          child: 
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Form(
                    child: new Container(
                      color: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
                      child:

                       Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Column(crossAxisAlignment: 
                         CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget> [
                              Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25.0, 0.0, 
                    0.0, 0.0),

                          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: 
                         CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget> [
                          Text(""),

                    Text(vm.state.subscriptions2[0].product.libelle,
                   textAlign:TextAlign.left,style:TextStyle()),

                  Text(vm.state.subscriptions2[0].product.description,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                         Expanded(
                        child:  ListView.builder(shrinkWrap:true,
                 itemCount: vm.state.subscriptions2.length,
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                         return  RadioListTile<double>(
                             title:Text( 
                 "${vm.state.subscriptions2[index].quota.libelle} 
             (${vm.state.subscriptions2[index].amount} CDF)"),

            value: vm.state.subscriptions2[index].amount,
          groupValue:vm.state.subscriptions2[index].amount,
          onChanged: (double value) {
          setState(() {
            vm.state.subscriptions2[index].amount = value;
          });
        },

                            );
  }), 
                         ),
                         ])


                                ),



                          _getActionButtons(vm),
                          SizedBox(height: 100)
                        ]) ],
                      ),

                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
       ),
     );
    },
  );
  }
```

i have this error while running : **RenderBox was not laid out**

Comment: try to use the `RadioListTile` widget

Comment: i tried with one radiobutton before adding listView and it appears, i don't think the problem is the widget but the listView's height

Comment: What is the parent widget of ListView.builder? Can you try adding `shrinkWrap:true`?

Comment: the parent widget is a column

Comment: yes i tried shrinkwrap:true but even there, it doesn't work, nothing appears

Comment: wrap the `ListView` by an `Expanded` widget

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: @RamsesKouam You say 'nothing appears' so could you edit your question and add the rest of your build function. Or even your entire class, maybe something else is causing the issue.

Comment: i have edited it